# A monotonic systemd timer that is not distorted by suspension and downtime?

Tags: systemd, cron, systemd-timer

This is what I want: **A timer that runs every X minutes *by the wall clock*. If the computer is asleep, then it should run as soon as it wakes up. And then again and again, every X minutes *by the wall clock*.**

**NOT** after X minutes have expired on `systemd`'s stopwatch (`OnActiveSec` etc). This stopwatch is paused for arbitrary periods, i.e. whenever the computer is suspended or turned off. So if want "every 36 hours" I have to do predictive calculations to derive a frequency based on what times the computer might be sleeping. Silly.

**NOT** at exact dates and times (`OnCalendar`), Doing it that way, whenever a timer is late (after down time) the following one will run too soon.

**I just want my timer to run (say) after 36 hours or as soon as it is awake thereafter. And then again, after 36 hours or as soon as it is awake thereafter.**

`systemd` timers seem to have everything covered except this basic use case. What am I missing? Do I really have to roll my own script for it?

**CLARIFICATION:** The `WakeSystem=true` option will cause `systemd` to use `CLOCK_BOOTTIME` instead of `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`. Great! Except that it will also wake the system. That is not what I want.

Comment: From [`man systemd.timer`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man5/systemd.timer.5.html): "Note
           that if WakeSystem= is used, a different monotonic clock is selected that continues to
           advance while the system is suspended and thus can be used as the trigger to resume
           the system." If that's not in your manpage, which version of systemd are you using?

Comment: @muru The manpage says not just that `WakeSystem=` "_can_ be used as the trigger" but that it "_will_ cause the system to suspend from suspend". That is explicitly not what I want, I want it to run "as soon as possible" after the wall-clock time has elapsed, i.e. after waking up. As it stands, to achieve this I'm going to have to write a script that creates and deletes transient timers based on `OnCalendar=` and timestamps. Seems ridiculous given the obviousness of the use case.

Comment: *correction to 2nd quote - "to _resume_ from suspend"

Comment: So you want the sleeping system to remain sleeping, even when the time has elapsed?

Comment: _"I just want my timer to run (say) every 36 hours or as soon as possible thereafter. And then again, every 36 hours or as soon as possible thereafter."_ So "ASAP" implies "now or else after the computer wakes up". I couldn't think of a more concise way to express this simple concept. Can you?

Comment: Note: ASAP may mean "if it's possible to wake up then wake up and do the task now".

Comment: Indeed, you are both right. Have edited question to be as explicit as possible.